# increasing sequence - convergence prediction

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, statistics, convergence-divergence

Is there a practical(≈statistic) method to predict whether an increasing real sequence converge or diverge ?

For example, the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes

Without knowing any number theory knowledge, but with a bunch of data of the first million terms of $x_n$,

$x_n$ = sum of reciprocals of the first $n$ primes

Can we predict whether $x_n$ will eventually converge or diverge ?

The answer may be a form of probability, or a distribution(the value of the limit).

Comment: In general, no. Those that we know diverge (like the reciprocal of the primes) or converge (like the reciprocals of the twin primes) we know because they had to be individually figured out. In the case of the first, even Euler's first proof was dubious.

Comment: Thank you, but I think the intent of my question was misrepresented a little. My new question is  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4786953/statistical-test-for-convergence-of-an-increasing-sequence

Answer (score 1):

There are many comparison theorems that students learn in Calculus 2 about the convergence and divergence of series. For example, If a sequence grows like $n^{1+\epsilon}$ for any positive $\epsilon$ then its sum of reciprocals will converge. If a sequence grows linearly, then its sum of reciprocals will diverge.
If a sequence grows as $n*\log(n)$ the sum of reciprocals diverges but $n*(\log(n))^{1+\epsilon}$ converges. Further, $n*\log(n)*\log(\log(n))$ diverges but $n*\log(n)*\log(\log(n))^{1+\epsilon}$ converges. You can find these in a first year calculus textbook.

So, yes, much is known about growth rates and the convergence of the sum of reciprocals. But the examples you mention involving prime numbers are really difficult because their asymptotic growth rate is difficult to state and it is also right around this boundary of convergence and divergence around $n*\log(n)$.

Comment: You'd better say something along the lines _"pretty close to that boundary of convergence"_. No function is right on the boundary.

Comment: Thank you, but I think the intent of my question was misrepresented a little. My new question is  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4786953/statistical-test-for-convergence-of-an-increasing-sequence

Comment: @imidak your question still won't get an answer. 10000 terms (or any finite number) tells nothing about infinite behaviour. You are probably best to see if you can fit the points to the best line of fit in the form of 1/n^k or 1/(n*log(n)^k) and if k is greater than 1, then convergence is plausible while if k <= 1 then divergence is more likely.