# Statistical test for convergence of an increasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, statistics, convergence-divergence, hypothesis-testing

Given a data :
a finite sequence of 10000 terms of increasing real numbers,
each expressed as decimal form, up to 20th decimal place,

Also suppose that the data was obtained while testing a conjecture in number theory,
so that it is possible to generate beyond 10000-th term.
You can think the data was actually the first 10000 term of the infinite sequence.

**Is there a statistical test** for convergence of the infinite sequence ?

The input : 10000 real numbers of decimal form upto 20 deciaml places
The output : probability 0 to 1 or just likely/unlikey with or without significance.

Comment: In general, no, the reason being very simply that no number of finite terms of a sequence determines a unique infinite sequence without additional constraints, so you'll have to elaborate a bit on the context if you want a more meaningful answer

Comment: Do you have a proposed distribution for the null hypothesis?

Comment: @Jose Avilez , no there is no proposed distribution. After getting some answers and comments, I think I'd be lucky if there was a way to test whether the sequence would just converge or diverge.  Investigating the value of limit (distribution) seems hoping too much.